# Car Database Array & Loops

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, random

This code doesn't seem to be working. I don't really know what loop to use to get it too add the information the user puts into the machine to print again.

The aim of this is for the user to either pick:

First of all I need to use this array to let the user enter there information into the database. Using an array. However it lets them type things but then I close the program and then it  doesn't print it into the database next time I run the program.

1.to print a menu that they have typed in an earlier database. If they haven't typed anything into the database, then it should be blank

2.Do error checking so that it tells them if they have entered a number when they should have entered a letter.

3.To end the program. 
Here is the code.

```
Module Module1

Structure Car           
    Public carmake As String           
    Public carmodel As String         
    Public caryear As Integer       
    Public carlicence As String
End Structure

Sub Main()

Dim userchoice

Console.WriteLine("Choose weather to open the database(1), print it (2) or end (3)")

        userchoice = Console.ReadLine()
        If userchoice = "1" Then
            Dim cardatabase(4) As Car
            Console.WriteLine("This will allow you to view the database.")
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the car make,licence,model and year")
            cardatabase(1).carmake = Console.ReadLine()
            cardatabase(1).carlicence = Console.ReadLine()
            cardatabase(1).carmodel = Console.ReadLine()
            cardatabase(1).caryear = Console.ReadLine()


        ElseIf userchoice = "2" Then
            Console.WriteLine("The database is,")
        ElseIf userchoice = "3" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using this program.")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: you just need to store the values entered into a local variable and then use console.writeline to print it out again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Car Database Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219492/car-database-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Structures are a group of variables that can only reside in memory. If you want to store your data permanently you have to use text files or real databases (Access or SQL). However, you can add records in a temporary way using arrays. I used your code to implement it with arrays which is a better way you can have your temporary database.

Module Module1

```
Structure Car
    Public carmake() As String
    Public carlicence() As String
    Public carmodel() As String
    Public caryear() As Integer
End Structure

Sub Main()

    Dim userchoice As String
    Dim cardatabase As Car

    cardatabase.carmake = {}
    cardatabase.carlicence = {}
    cardatabase.carmodel = {}
    cardatabase.caryear = {}

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Choose weather to open the database(1), print it (2) or end (3)")
        userchoice = Console.ReadLine()
        If userchoice = "1" Then
            Console.WriteLine("This will allow you to view the database.")
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the car make,licence,model and year")
            ReDim Preserve cardatabase.carmake(i)
            ReDim Preserve cardatabase.carlicence(i)
            ReDim Preserve cardatabase.carmodel(i)
            ReDim Preserve cardatabase.caryear(i)
            cardatabase.carmake(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            cardatabase.carlicence(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            cardatabase.carmodel(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            cardatabase.caryear(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            i += 1
        ElseIf userchoice = "2" Then
            For index = 0 To i - 1
                Console.WriteLine("The database is {0} - {1} - {2} - {3},", cardatabase.carmake(index),
                                 cardatabase.carlicence(index),
                              cardatabase.carmodel(index), cardatabase.caryear(index))
            Next
        ElseIf userchoice = "3" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using this program.")
        End If
    Loop Until userchoice = "3"
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

End Module